# algebra homework question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $$f(x)= \frac {1}{e^{1-2x}+1}$$Find $$f\left(\frac {1}{2009}\right)+f\left(\frac {2}{2009}\right)+f\left(\frac {3}{2009}\right)+ \cdots +f\left(\frac {2008}{2009}\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apply Gauss' idea --- collapsing symmetric terms, which suggests us considering evaluating for $x \in (0, 1/2)$, 
\begin{align}
& f(x) + f(1 - x) \\
= & \frac{1}{1 + e^{1 - 2x}} + \frac{1}{1 + e^{1 - 2(1 - x)}} \\
= & \frac{1}{1 + e^{1 - 2x}} + \frac{1}{1 + e^{-1 + 2x}} \\
= & 1.
\end{align} 
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$f(x) +f(1-x)=1$

So, the answer is $1004$, as there are $1004$ pairs of $x$ and $(1-x)$, like $\frac{1}{2009}$ and $\frac{2008}{2009}$ and so on.

Comment: Could you please give some hint why f(x)+f(1-x)=1. or maybe a source to read about it.

Comment: Why the downvote?